# El valor de BOF o EOF es True, o el actual registro se eliminó; la operación solicitada requiere un registro actual

Tags: vb6

Tengo una consulta la cual me devuelve ciertos datos para mostrarlos en cajas de texto, y valido que no estén vacíos de la siguiente manera:

```html
ExecCmd
Set RsGral = CmdGral.Execute
CmdGral.CommandType = adCmdText
If RsGral.RecordCount > 0 Then

 If Trim(RsGral!CodLocalidad) <> "" Then
 TxtIdLocalidad.Text = Trim(RsGral!CodLocalidad)
 TxtIdLocalidad.Tag = Trim(RsGral!CodLocalidad)
Else
 TxtIdLocalidad.Text = ""
End If
End if
```

Pero en algunos datos me muestra el error `El valor de BOF o EOF es True, o el actual registro se eliminó; la operación solicitada requiere un registro actual` aunque el registro si tenga datos
Depurando descubrí que el valor de EOF es siempre verdadero mientras que BOF es falso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese error ocurre cuando estás fuera de los límites del Recordset, bien sea porque hiciste un recorrido registro a registro con los métodos `MoveNext` o `MovePrevious` o porque la consulta no devolvió resultados. [Mas información](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/bof-eof-properties-ado?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=BOF%20Indicates%20that%20the%20current,record%20in%20a%20Recordset%20object.)

Como regla general, deberías validar si una consulta devuelve resultados antes de comenzar a utilizar el Recordset.
En esta versión de ADO la forma de comprobarlo es validando las propiedades `BOF` y `EOF` del recordset.

```
If RsGral.BOF And RsGral.EOF Then
    'En este punto la consulta no devolvió resultado porque Ambas propiedades son true

    TxtIdLocalidad.Text = ""
else
    'En este punto el recordset tiene información y es seguro trabajar con el.

    If Trim(RsGral!CodLocalidad) <> "" Then
        TxtIdLocalidad.Text = Trim(RsGral!CodLocalidad)
        TxtIdLocalidad.Tag = Trim(RsGral!CodLocalidad)
    Else
        TxtIdLocalidad.Text = ""
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Hola gracias por su respuesta ya añadí esta validación If RsGral.BOF And RsGral.EOF Then en cada txt, ahora no me muestra el error pero ese registro si tiene data y sigue sin mostrarlo de todos modos

Comment: Me puedes comentar de qué forma estas validando que efectivamente hay un registro? porque cuando las propiedades BOF y EOF son true, es porque el resordset está vacío

Comment: asi Debug.Print RsGral.Fields(0), RsGral.Fields(1), RsGral.Fields(2),imprimo cada registro y si tiene data, ademas la consulta la saco de mi base de datos SQL Server y ahi veo que si hay datos, ademas si no hay ya lo he validado como isnull(codLocalidad,0) as CodLocalidad

Comment: y sigue mandando el mismo mensaje, no lo comprendo :c

Comment: Dices que imprimes cada registro, eso me hace suponer que estás recorriendo el recordset para imprimirlo. ¿Utilizas `RsGral.MoveNext` en algun punto antes de llegar al bloque de codigo donde asignas los txt?

Comment: no uso MoveNext, imprimo los registros asi TxtIdLocalidad.Text = Trim(RsGral!CodLocalidad), cada uno en su caja de texto correspondiente, pero uso debug.print nomas para comprobar que si hay datos y si los hay

Comment: Y si haces `Debug.Print RsGral!CodLocalidad` funciona igual que `Debug.Print RsGral.Fields(0)`

Comment: si, si funciona, si CodLocalidad tiene valor lo imprime, sino imprime un 0

Comment: el error es cuando lo quiero poner en el TxtIdLocalidad

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113671/discussion-between-pablo-gutierrez-and-huntzberger).